# SwiftUI 4: scrollTo() generates invalid UI in VStack and LazyVStack

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-vstack

See the code below. The setup:

- There are only 3 items in the `LazyVStack`.
- The code scroll to the last item when the view is shown on the screen.

The result:

```
 +--------------+   +--------------+
 |      c       |   |      a       |
 |              |   |      b       |
 |              |   |      c       |
 |              |   |              |
 |              |   |              |
 |              |   |              |
 |              |   |              |
 |              |   |              |
 +--------------+   +--------------+

   What I saw        What I expected
```

Although the code pass `.top` param to `scrollTo()`, I expected all 3 items are shown on the screen because there are enough space on the screen (this is the behavior of calling `scrollTo` in `List`). However, `LazyVStack` only shows the third one. `VStack` has the same issue.

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var value: String
}

struct TestView: View {
    var items: [Item]
    var scrollTo: UUID
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack {
                    ForEach(items) { item in
                        Text(item.value)
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                        proxy.scrollTo(scrollTo, anchor: .top)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var items: [Item] =  [Item(value: "a"), Item(value: "b"), Item(value: "c")]
    
    var body: some View {
        TestView(items: items, scrollTo: items.last!.id)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
```

While `LazyVStack` and `VStack`'s behavior seems to fit well with `.top` semantics, I find it's very confusing because it generates an invalid and misleading UI (it's impossible for user to create such UI interactively). List's behavior, however, makes more sense.

I googled this but didn't find related discussion. I filed FB12173661 to report the issue. I wonder if anyone know how to work around it? My current workaround is to change `.top` to `.center`. It doesn't solve the issue completely (only `.bottom` can, but I don't want to use it).

---

**UPDATE**: I did an experiment by adding animation. The result helped to indicate what happened under the hood. `LazyVStack` actually showed all three items on the screen at first, and then scrolled up and moved the first two items outside screen and stopped there. It really looks like a bug to me.

```
.onAppear {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        withAnimation {
            proxy.scrollTo(scrollTo, anchor: .top)
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**: Two more information:

- I upgraded my phone from iOS 16.3.1 to 16.4. The issue persisted.
- LazyVGrid has the same issue.
  It seems using List is the only option to get the correct scrolling behavior.